# Not sure why this function does not work?

Tags: python, function

Want to take an input for radius and return area and circumference. However when run, no errors but nothing happens. What am i missing pleae

```
def circle ( radius ):
    pi = 3.141592
    a = pi * radius **2
    c = 2 * pi * radius
    print (f'Area is {a} and the circumference is {c}')
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" you should be specific about the part of it's that not working. Did you get an error? Include it in your question. Did you get the wrong result? Say what result you got and describe what the right result is.

Comment: Are you calling your function properly (`circle(5)`)?

Comment: I see, thankyou for the comment, this was my first post so wasnt too sure on. Ill edit now!

Comment: @Wondercricket im sorry but i dont understand what you are suggesting?

Comment: You've shown us your function definition, but haven't shown how you're invoking the function. That should be part of the question as well.

Comment: @mason thankyou for responding I am a complete beginner, i shall ammend my comment now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code (call to `circle()`), example input, expected output, and actual output (may be no output in this case). For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So it looks like youre having issues understanding how to invoke the function.

Look at this code, see how i assign this to be equal to circle(77)? That is one way of invoking the function. Note that your functions can be in seperate files where you can import them from. If theyre in the same file, theyll need to be above any code referencing them.

```
def circle(radius):
    pi = 3.141592
    a = 2 * radius * pi
    c = 2 * pi * radius
    print (f'Area is '+str(a)+' and the circumference is '+str(c))

#this line invokes the function   
this = circle(77)
```

[image]

Comment: `this = None` since `circle()` doesn't return anything